# get date format by locale

Tags: java, date, parsing, internationalization

I need a method whom I can pass locale (and style, probably), and who should return me date-formatting string. For example `getDateFormatString(new Locale("en-US"), FormatStyle.SHORT)` would return "M/dd/yy".

It is not enough for me to use something like `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT).withLocale(locale);` for parsing, because I also need to parse format variations, for example to interpret M/dd as date in current year, so I want to make variations on original format string.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate currentYearAtGivenMonthDay =

Year.now( 
    ZonedId.of( "America/Montreal" )
).atMonthDay(
    MonthDay.parse( "1/7" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "M/d"
) )
```

## Details

The java.time classes have some very specific types.

## `MonthDay`

For your month-day, use the [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html) class. Use a `DateTimeFormatter` to specify any non-standard (ISO 8601) formatted input strings.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "M/d" );
MonthDay md = MonthDay.parse( yourInput , f );
```

Assign a year to get a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = md.atYear( 2017 );
```

To determine current year instead of hard-coding a year number, use `Year` class. Specify a time zone as for any given moment the date varies around the globe by zone, and therefore the year can vary around December 31 to January 1.

```
ZoneId z = ZonedId.of( "America/Montreal" );
Year currentYear = Year.now( z );
LocalDate ld = currentYear.atMonthDay( md );
```

Similar types include `YearMonth` and `Year` and `Month`.

Also peruse the ThreeTen-Extra project for more classes that work with java.time.

## `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`

For complicated variations not possible by formatting patterns, consider building up a `DateTimeFormatter` using the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`. Search Stack Overflow for discussion and examples.

Comment: How can I get this "M/d" pattern ? I need algorithm which returns that (or something similar) for US locale, and "d.M" for Serbian locale. And I'd like to resolve it in java8, and avoid using SimpleDateFormat class if possible.

Comment: @zmau For parsing when either format may appear? Search the string for the dot or the slash. Or try parsing one format arbitrarily, trap for exception, in which case try the other format. Even better is to use standard ISO 8601 formats when serializing such values: `--MM-DD` for month-day such as January 23 being `--01-23`.